# scrapyd - error while running spiders simultaneously

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm trying to run two scrapy spiders simultaneously using scrapyd.
I execute

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider
```

result - {"status": "ok", "jobid": "6487ec79947edab326d6db28a2d86511e8247444"}
then:

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=somespider2
```

result -

```
    python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 234, in render
            body = resrc.render(self)
        --- <exception caught here>
        File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
            exceptions.ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

and everytime I run curl for scrapyd - I get the same - exceptions.ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded. The only one way to proceed working with scrapyd - to restart it.
How can I run multiple spiders with scrapyd? Why do I get that error?

---

I use scrapy 1.1, scrapyd 1.1, python 2.7.9

Comment: Presumably the problem relates to sqlite3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in sqlite3 installed in my Centos6.5.
Decision:
need to add

```
self.conn.text_factory = bytes
```

to SqliteDict and SqlitePriorityQueue classes after connect creation in a `scrapyd/sqlite.py b/scrapyd/sqlite.py`

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do the scrapyd, most probably the error is in your spider 'somespider2'. Just ensure that you are able to run 'somespider2' properly via command line.

Comment: So why the same error occurs when I run someSpider twise? (First time scrapyd returned job ID) Evenmore, I get the same error if I execute curl with 'listspiders' params twice. (First time scrapid returns correct result)